# Php call static functions in a function

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to call a static function from a class in a function. In pseudo code, something like this:

```
function process_image($file_name) {
  $file_tmp_loc = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"];
  move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_loc, 'uploads/' . $file_name);

  require("GifFrameExtractor.php");

  $gif_file_path = 'uploads/' . $file_name;
  if (GifFrameExtractor::isAnimatedGif($gif_file_path)) { 
    //do stuff here
  }
}
```

I've required the class to which I am calling in the actual function but yet I keep getting a class not found error. This file is sitting in the same directory as the script trying to use it with 777 permissions. I keep getting this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'GifFrameExtractor' not found in ...../functions.php on line 557

I could really care less if this is in bad form OOP wise as long as the code works, so I'm not looking for any lectures or questions as to why I would do such a thing, unless that is precisely why I can't do them. I know the file is being included because I don't have any `require()` or iostream errors.

For those that are wondering, I'm trying to implement [this](https://github.com/Sybio/GifFrameExtractor) class from Github

Comment: did you use namespace?

Comment: The code we see looks okay so far. We do not have any information about the `GifFrameExtractor` class to diagnose any further problems with it.

Comment: yeah, messed it up even more: use GifFrameExtractor\GifFrameExtractor as GifFrameExtractor;

Comment: @donald123 Yeah, after going through the include files I saw they had a bunch of namespaces that was throwing everything off. Once I commented those out, code is working like a dream. Put down a formal answer and I'll give you a green checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That class is meant to be installed with [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/)

That means it is usually namespaced. In order to be able to use that class you have to **[import the namespace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)**.

If you are not using composer you have to make sure that you install all the dependencies required by the package by yourself. Luckily this class does not have any (besides having PHP >=5.3.0)

So you can just include it and import the namespace.

Do something like this:

```
<?php

include 'src/GifFrameExtractor/GifFrameExtractor.php';

use GifFrameExtractor\GifFrameExtractor AS GifFrameExtractor;

function doSomeStuff()
{
    GifFrameExtractor::isAnimatedGif('test.gif');
}

doSomeStuff();
```

You could also drop the use statement and use a fully qualified namespace:

```
<?php

include 'src/GifFrameExtractor/GifFrameExtractor.php';

function doSomeStuff()
{
    GifFrameExtractor\GifFrameExtractor::isAnimatedGif('test.gif');
}

doSomeStuff();
```

Generally if a package is using composer, also install it via composer. Otherwise you could encounter some unwanted and unneccessary behavior (if dependencies are required by the packages)